# InnoSetup - GIF backgroung image?

Tags: inno-setup, animated-gif, pascalscript

I use the following code to display a background image in InnoSetup,

```
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  BackgroundImage: TBitmapImage;
begin
  BackgroundImage := TBitmapImage.Create(MainForm);
  BackgroundImage.Parent := MainForm;
  BackgroundImage.SetBounds(0, 0, MainForm.ClientWidth, MainForm.ClientHeight);
  BackgroundImage.Stretch := True;
  BackgroundImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('C:\image.gif'))
end;
```

But this does not work for GIF animated images. Is there a way in InnoSetup to display GIF images in the background or loop through bitmap images?

Comment: Only BMP is supported. Simply convert your GIF to BMP. Or are you actually asking about animated GIF (from your reference to “loop through bitmap images”)?

Comment: If the GIF is not possible then is there a way to add more than one bitmap image as background and loop through it?